# Display what is in HTML.HiddenFor or Save Display

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Call me crazy but this seems incredibly redundant and unnecessary but for the life of me I can't find a function that achieves both.

```
using Html.BeginForm("Save, Home") {


   @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Id)
   @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)

   @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.CreatedDate)
   @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CreatedDate)

   //Useful fields below

}
```

Let me explain - I want to save the CreatedDate and Id values, hence the hiddenFor. This of course generates an input behind the scenes, but I also need to display it. DisplayFor, and ValueFor both return Id = 0 on my form submission. More specifically when I update the data in the form, I would like to retain those two values. The model returned has them at 0/Datetime year 0.

Is there not a way to save those values for the next model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an extension method:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString DisplayAndHiddenFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, 
        Func<TModel, TProperty> propertyAccessor)
    {
        return new HtmlString(
            helper.DisplayFor(propertyAccessor).ToHtmlString()
            + helper.HiddenFor(propertyAccessor).ToHtmlString());
    }
}
```

Used like this (with the proper `using` of course):

```
@Html.DisplayAndHiddenFor(x => x.Id)
@Html.DisplayAndHiddenFor(x => x.CreatedDate)
```